# This Keyword + DOM Element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm creating script that will add *,* at every unordered list's list element with exception for the last list element - it should end with *;*. This should happen for each unordered list!

It's like...

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

...to:

```
<ul>
  <li>a,</li>
  <li>b,</li>
  <li>c;</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>d,</li>
  <li>e,</li>
  <li>f;</li>
</ul>
```

My code looks like this at the moment...

```
$('ul').each(function(i) {
    var listsLength = $(this + 'li').length;
    $(this + 'li').each(function(j) {
        if (i == (listsLength - 1)) {
            $(this).append(';');
        } else {
            $(this).append(',');
        }
    });
}
```

I think that problem is this code...

```
$( this + 'li' )
```

Any idea how to get the same effect?

**Edit:**

Fixed it. There was actually syntax error as well and also I used *i* where *j* should be placed. Now all works and here's [the outcome](http://pastie.org/1927760).

**Edit #2:**

Just use @lonesomeday code... it's much readable and lightweight!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do `this + 'li'`.  `this`, in this context, is a DOM element, not a string.  To get the effect you want, you'd need `$(this).find('li')`.

Your loop is also unnecessary.  You can do something far better with [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/):

```
$('ul li:last-child').append(';');
$('ul li:not(:last-child)').append(',');
```

Those two lines will have the effect you want.

Comment: @Rocket It could be one, of course... `$('li').filter(':last-child').append(';').end().filter(':not(:last-child)').append(',');` But that isn't as readable!

Comment: @lonesomeday: Even better: `$('li', 'ul').append(function(){return $(this).is(':last-child') ? ';' : ','});`

Comment: @lonesome: But it does rid yourself of that naughty redundant DOM selection. ;o) Maybe: `$('ul li').slice(0,-1).append(',').end().slice(-1).append(';');`

Comment: @Rocket: Yep, you're absolutely right. Just looked at the HTML. Probably should have done that first!

Comment: @daGrevis :-P. thats all i have to say hehe

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$( this + 'li' )` do `$( 'li', this )`

Answer (score 1):

`this + 'li'` will try to convert `this` to a string, and then concat `'li'` to it.

Try this instead:

```
$('li', this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$(this).find ('>li').each(...)
```

instead (if the problem is really here).